# How to add two databases in my application? Is it a good practice?

Tags: android, database, firebase, cloudinary

I am working on an application which requires fetching the video from the server and i need user authentication where the user can only watch the Videos if they have paid the fee. Now someone suggested me to work with two databases, which is to fetch the video from cloudinary database(It's quick) and use firebase to store the user information. Now the problem is i don't know how to do it and whether it is a good idea to use two database in one project.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no inherent technical problem with using multiple databases in an application. In fact, depending on how you define a database, there are probably already multiple databases in use before your code even gets executed.

Just follow the documentation for each of the databases to add them to the app, and to interact with them. If you get stuck with one of them, post a question with the [minimal steps how anyone can reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most often this will only require one of the databases.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will surely look for a way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

As you said someone advise you to use two database.

Firebase Provides you two different database types.

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). For more guidance there is docs available on given link.

For Database structure for your application.

**1. Firestore Database Structure :**

```
User
  -> user_id(uid of [Firebase Auth][3])
         - name
         - user_payment : Paid or unpaid
         - user other details
```

**2. Firebase Realtime Database Structure :**

```
Users
  ->paid_users(uid)
        - user details
  ->unpaid users(uid)
        - user details
```

From the above structure you (->) this symbol is used as **Collection** and (-) this symbol is used for **Fields** of Collection or Document. if you want more details just comment down.

Comment: Thank you, The thing is firebase is too slow when fetching the video, that is why i had to look for other options. And does the free version provide above functionality?

Comment: there are limits for free version if you read pricing about [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) and [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits).

Comment: Ok thank you i will try to implement and see where it goes.

Comment: There links i have provided for docs and need any help just post the question by using firebase tag

Comment: Ok i will implement and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

to do or not to do, it's depends upon situation but
here is Completely working code to add two databases in android application. 

Two separate files for two databases and one MainActivity.java

1. DatabaseFaculty.java
2. DatabaseStudent.java
3. MainActivity.java

DatabaseFaculty.java

```
public class DatabaseFaculty {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="dbfaculty";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="tablefaculty";
public static final int DATABSE_VERSION=1;


public static final String FID="fid";
public static final String FNAME="fname";


//to create a table
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_FACULTY="create table tablefaculty(fid INTEGER, fname TEXT);";

private Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;  // manipulation with database
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

public DatabaseFaculty(Context ctx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=ctx;
    dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}


//SQLITEOpenHelper has methods to creae and open
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //DatabaseHelper's constructor will create the database
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_FACULTY);
        Log.d("table is created..","tablefaculty");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);
    }


}


public DatabaseFaculty Open() throws SQLException
{
        db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
}

public void close()
{
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertData(int fid,String fname)
{
        ContentValues initialvalues=new ContentValues();

        initialvalues.put(FID, fid);
        initialvalues.put(FNAME,fname);

        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,initialvalues);

}

public Cursor getNames()
{
    String query="SELECT fname FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cur;
}


public void getFacultyDetail(String rfid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,  FID + " = ?",  new String[] { rfid});
    Log.d("Delete called....","Delete called.....");

}
}
```

DatabaseStudent.java

```
public class DatabaseStudent {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="dbstudent";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="tablestudent";
public static final int DATABSE_VERSION=1;


public static final String ROLLNO="rollno";
public static final String SNAME="sname";
public static final String CITY="city";


//to create a table
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_STUDENT="create table tablestudent(rollno INTEGER, sname TEXT, city TEXT);";

private Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;  // manipulation with database
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

public DatabaseStudent(Context ctx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=ctx;
    dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}


//SQLITEOpenHelper has methods to creae and open
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //DatabaseHelper's constructor will create the database
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_STUDENT);
        Log.d("table is created..","tablestudent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);
    }


}


public DatabaseStudent Open() throws SQLException
{
        db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
}

public void close()
{
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertData(int rollno,String sname,String city)
{
        ContentValues initialvalues=new ContentValues();

        initialvalues.put(ROLLNO, rollno);
        initialvalues.put(SNAME,sname);
        initialvalues.put(CITY,city);

        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,initialvalues);

}

public Cursor getNames()
{
    String query="SELECT fname FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cur;
}




public void deleteStudentDetail(String rrollno) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,  ROLLNO + " = ?",  new String[] { rrollno});
    Log.d("Delete called....","Delete called.....");

}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseFaculty databaseFaculty;
DatabaseStudent databaseStudent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    databaseFaculty=new DatabaseFaculty(getApplicationContext());
    databaseFaculty.Open();
    databaseFaculty.close();

    databaseStudent=new DatabaseStudent(getApplicationContext());
    databaseStudent.Open();
    databaseStudent.close();

}
}
```

Sure, it will be helpful and worked successfully.

Comment: Thank you, will try to implement it.